# Codeigniter - Login check is always failed

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working login and registration with codeigniter, registration works fine but login check is failing and can't able to find the solution.

Here is model and controller.

Model (User_model.php)

```
    public function resolve_user_login($email, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('password');
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $hash = $this->db->get()->row('password');
        return $this->verify_password_hash($password, $hash);
    }

    private function verify_password_hash($password, $hash)
    {
        return password_verify($password, $hash);
    }
```

Controller (User.php)

```
public function login()
{
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['title'] = 'Login';

            $this->load->view('default/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('default/login');
            $this->load->view('default/footer');
        } else {

            if ($this->User_model->resolve_user_login($email, $password))
            {
                echo 'Everything is good';

            } else {
                // error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Wrong e-mail or password</div>');
                redirect('login');
            }

        }

}

private function hash_password($password)
{
    return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
}
```

When i enter correct email and password it showing wrong email and password results.

Comment: No function code for that

Comment: does `$hash = $this->db->get()->row('password');` gives you expected password hash from the database ?

Comment: How to i know this giving result or not. ?

Comment: use `var_dump($hash);` and then terminate script using `die();` or `exit();`

Comment: Yes result coming same. db password and hash.

Comment: what do you mean by "db password and hash" ?  you should be only getting the hash

Comment: I am getting only hash after submit login form which is in the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131737/discussion-between-ranjanalk-and-rahamathullah-mohamed-kasim).

Comment: Have you dumped the password content after `$password = $this->input->post('password');`? I just replicated your code and it works. The problem is either getting the password from your form or saving the hash in the registration phase.

Comment: @Hicaro Yes i dumped and its showing password as string not hash

Comment: Could you post the hash from database and the password you are trying to use? I wanted to test here.

Comment: password is: test123 and hash if different by user but same password.

Answer (score 1):

Change your model function like this. Note that you do not need verify_password_hash() function anymore if you use below code.

```
public function resolve_user_login($email, $password)
    {
       $query = $this
                ->db
                ->where('email',$email)
                ->where('password',password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT))
                ->limit(1)
                ->get('user');

        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and in controller a little change

```
if ($this->User_model->resolve_user_login($email, $password)!==False)
            {
                echo 'Everything is good';

            }
```

Really hope this method work for you. If not specify errors in comments.

Comment: I not using md5 encryption i am using following in Controller
`private function hash_password($password)
    {
        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    }`

Comment: Yes and i have added that function in the question (controller) code

Comment: please try again now .. I made an edit in your model and change the md5 to bcrypt.

Comment: I made changes in following line:
`->where('password',password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT))` to `->select('password',password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT))`

Comment: Are you using bcrypt with any random salt when storing password at time of user registration.. password_hash function is used to convert your entered password to just normal bcrypt hash. Check your password hash in database with hash that you generated from password_hash function by writing a simple separate PHP script.

Answer (score -1):

there is no way (yet) for decrypting hashes like bcyrpt or codeigenter's hash you can use php's method `password_verify('your_word', 'the_hash' );` make a condition where if it returns true then you are able to login.